# About adding prerequisites to make setup files on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, installation, prerequisites, deployment-project

I know that if you want your setup files to detect whether the pc have .Net Framework 3.5 installed, you must configure the prerequisites in the Setup Properties. There 3 options to choose from and I'm not quite understand what is the second options means: "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application".
Is it that I must get the .Net Framework 3.5 installation files ready first? Where should I put this installation files?

Answer (score 0):

it's for distributing the prerequisites with your installer (like an offline-installer):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873130.aspx